# php script to export mysql db via cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I've discovered the [Cpanel PHP API](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome) which allows basic communication with the [MYSQL db's](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api1/ApiMysql) but is it possible to use it to export specific tables from a database. Looking for an example if there is one out there.

Thanks

Comment: usually Cpanel comes with phpmyadmin, that has a tool that exports the sql

Comment: true - but its a manual process, i want to capture the steps in a script